# Style an image to be at the top-right of a div

Tags: html, image, css, styles, css-position

I want to style an image to be at the top right corner of a div, how do I achieve this? Please help out.[image: I want to style this to reflect this screenshot]

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .first{
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            color: blue;
            border: blue;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: blue;
            background: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="first">testing this forum
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div {
    height: 175px;
    width: 175px;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    /* Additionally padding? */
}

div > img {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px; right: 0px; 
    /* Change top < 0 and right < 0 to be outside */
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque velit elit, tempus non suscipit id, pretium a mi. Aliquam erat volutpat.
  <img src="http://maciejczyzewski.me/assets/images/prints/head.jpeg" />
</div>
```